# Splitting Shortcode Attributes not working

Tags: shortcode

I want to adjust a comparison based on attributes I define in my shortcode. As example I use the following short code:

```
[comparison phonePrefix="0581",phoneFlatOption="true", 
accessModeDsl="true", accessModeCable="false", accessModeLte="false", 
accessModeSat="false"]
```

Now here is my shortcode function:

```
function comparison($atts){

$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
        'phonePrefix' => '030',
        'customerType' => 'existingCustomer',
        'remainingContractDuration' => '6',
        'phoneFlatOption' => 'true',
        'minSpeed' => '50000',
        'accessModeDsl' => 'true',
        'onlyProductsWithoutTrafficLimitation' => 'true',
        'accessModeCable' => 'true',
        'accessModeLte' => 'true',
        'accessModeSat' => 'true',
        'contractDuration' => '-1',
        'mergeDefaults' => 'false',
    ), $atts, 'dslVergleich');
 }
```

As I understood the `shortcode_atts()` function it should now replace the default value of `'phonePrefix'` with `0581`. But after I use the function there is still the default value of `030`.

This is a `var_dump` before I used `shortcode_atts()`:

```
array(5) { 
  [0]=> string(42) "phonePrefix="0581",phoneFlatOption="true"," 
  [1]=> string(21) "accessModeDsl="true","
  [2]=> string(24) "accessModeCable="false"," 
  [3]=> string(22) "accessModeLte="false"," 
  ["accessmodesat"]=> string(5) "false" 
}
```

And this is after I used `shortcode_atts()`:

```
array(12) {
  ["phonePrefix"]=> string(3) "030" 
  ["customerType"]=> string(16) "existingCustomer"     
  ["remainingContractDuration"]=> string(1) "6" 
  ["phoneFlatOption"]=> string(4) "true"
  ["minSpeed"]=> string(5) "50000" 
  ["accessModeDsl"]=> string(4) "true" 
  ["onlyProductsWithoutTrafficLimitation"]=> string(4) "true" 
  ["accessModeCable"]=> string(4) "true" 
  ["accessModeLte"]=> string(4) "true" 
  ["accessModeSat"]=> string(4) "true" 
  ["contractDuration"]=> string(2) "-1" 
  ["mergeDefaults"]=> string(5) "false"
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you don't have to use `,` for argument separation. try `[comparison phonePrefix="0581" phoneFlatOption="true" 
accessModeDsl="true" accessModeCable="false" accessModeLte="false" 
accessModeSat="false"]`

Answer (score 3):

The `var_dump()` before using `shortcode_atts()` reveals the problem. Lets look at that output in a more readable format:

```
array(5) { 
    [0] => string(42) "phonePrefix="0581",phoneFlatOption="true"," 
    [1]=> string(21) "accessModeDsl="true"," 
    [2]=> string(24) "accessModeCable="false"," 
    [3]=> string(22) "accessModeLte="false"," 
    ["accessmodesat"]=> string(5) "false"
}
```

As you can see, the attributes are not being parsed correctly. Instead of `'attribute' => 'value'` you're getting a numerically indexed array of broken bits of the shortcode.

This is because of the way you've written the shortcode, not anything in the shortcode code itself.

```
[comparison phonePrefix="0581",phoneFlatOption="true", 
accessModeDsl="true", accessModeCable="false", accessModeLte="false", 
accessModeSat="false"]
```

**The lack of spaces between the attributes and the use of commas is incorrect formatting for shortcodes.** It should be formatted like this:

```
[comparison phonePrefix="0581" phoneFlatOption="true" 
accessModeDsl="true" accessModeCable="false" accessModeLte="false" 
accessModeSat="false"]
```